# Use of CSS pseudo class `:scope` to style elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

From [mdn pseudo classes :scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope)

> The :scope CSS pseudo-class represents elements that are a reference
> point, or scope, for selectors to match against.

To my understanding a "custom" pseudo class for `:scope` can

1. be created and used from javascript using the [DOM Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Using_the_Document_Object_Model)
2. can not be used in style rules

#### Is my understanding correct?

In the code exmple below i want to style links that are children of `iamscoped` with the use of a pseudo class

```css
ul:first-child { font-size: 25px; color: red} /** <-- this works */
a:iamscoped { font-size: 35px; color: red} /** <-- this does not */
```

But to my understanding this is not possible and not intended since the scope will be created from javascript but does not exist yet for the style rendering.

```js
function colorScope() {
  const parentNode = document.getElementById("iamscoped");  
  // scope is now created using DOM Api
  const spans = parentNode.querySelectorAll(":scope span");
  spans.forEach((el) => {
    el.style.color = "red";
    el.style.fontSize = "2em"
  });
}
```

```css
a {color: black}
ul li:first-child { font-size: 20px; color: blue}
/** scope does not exist yet */
span:iamscoped { font-size: 35px; color: red}
span[xxuuas] {color: green; font-weight: bold; font-size:30px}
```

```html
<div id="iamscoped">
  <ul><li><span>scoped 1st list-item-child</span></li>
    <li><span>scoped</span></li>
  </ul>
  <span xxuuas>I am super-special</span>
</div>
<div id="unsocped">
  <ul>
    <li><span>unscoped 1st list-item</span></li>
    <li><span>unscoped span</span></li>
  </ul>
  <span xxuuas>I am super-special</span>
</div>
<button onclick="colorScope()">color scoped</button>
```

#### Is my understanding correct?

- The `scope` pseudo class can only be used via DOM API
- Can not be used inside a stylesheet
- Regarding `<span xxuuas>` and `span[xxuuas] {...}` this is somthing else - maybe named a [scope identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0)?

Comment: From the document you linked to: "*When used in a stylesheet, `:scope` is the same as `:root`, as there is currently no way to explicitly establish a scoped element*." So, no: (as yet) this exists in CSS for compatibility with `document.querySelector()` (and similar), but doesn't seem possible, or perhaps even relevant, within a stylesheet.

Comment: Do you want to change your comment to an answer?